# Date format mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
2018-09-21T01:21:48.310Z
```

Im currently using mongoDB, in the schema i have defined createdat as mongoose Data object. The stored format is this, does anyone know what this format is?

Comment: ISODate - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date

Comment: Wicked, thanks for that